# Set Height Programmatically for a Single UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I need to set the height for a single UITableViewCell in my UITableView programmatically. How can I do this?

I need this one cell to be 150 pixels high and all the others can stay at their default 44 pixels in height.

Thanks.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There is a delegate function for the UITableViewCell height.

Here you specify the indexPath of that particular cell and return your height for it

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(indexPath.section == yourSection && indexPath.row == yourRow) {
        return 150.0;
    }
    // "Else"
    return someDefaultHeight;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You will have to know, or figure out what cell index you want to make the taller one.
Lets say its your first cell.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.row == 0) { //change 0 to whatever cell index you want taller
        return 150;
    }
    else {
        return 44;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**SWIFT ANSWER**

Specify which section and row you want to change (remember the count starts at 0, not 1) in the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat{
    if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0{
        return 150
    }
    return 44.0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

You can set the value for the cell at a specific index path with this method, and a default value for the other cells.